# Cuda profiling speed concern

Tags: cuda, profiling

When I build an executable using nvcc, I can, by default, profile it using nvprof or Nvidia visual profiler GUI. My concern is that, even when I am not actually profiling it, my executable may not be running optimally, because it is 'able' to record or emit information about profiling. So, I am feeling like by default, executables are built with profiling enabled.

Strange that this question was not asked before, the answer is not obvious to me. Is there a compiler option to disable profiling, especially for release mode? Or is profiling completely free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a compiler option to disable profiling, especially for release mode? Or is profiling completely free?

There is no compiler option to disable profiling.  It is completely free.

Comment: Does this completely free include ptx instruction pmevent ?

Comment: You won't find `pmevent` emitted from compilation of ordinary CUDA C/C++ code which is what I assumed was in view here.  Of course if you code directly in PTX, and you encode a `pmevent` instruction, or use a CUDA C/C++ profiling API in your code which causes emission of a `pmevent` instruction, then you will pay for the cost of that instruction.  Having said all that, there are no compilation switches that vary the cost of `pmevent` in any way.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable complement.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for the answer, this was what I wanted to be sure. Can you also cite any official document mentioning this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly. Perhaps something like a read of the [profiler docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#prepare-application) would make sense, including this statement right up front: "The CUDA profiling tools do not require any application changes to enable profiling". The implication is that profiling support is transparent. If there *were* a way to build an app such that profiling support is disabled, then this would have to be pointed out in that section, so that a user would know how to properly prepare the application for profiling.